# Dissecting .csv Data

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I have created a script that downloads an Excel .cvs file, parses it and prints it to a google spreadsheet.
How can I access the different rows/columns individually so that I can choose where to print each set of values?

```
    function importFromCSV() {

//accesses excel doc with authorization
var fileName = UrlFetchApp.fetch("url_here"); 

var csvData = fileName.getBlob().getDataAsString();

//sanitize string to get rid of characters that are would cause parse to 
throw an error
var sanitizedString = csvData.replace(/(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2[\s\S])*?\1/g, 
function(e){return e.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ' ') });

// parseCsv returns a [][] array to write to sheet
var parsedData = Utilities.parseCsv(sanitizedString);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_id_here");
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

// boom data to a sheet
sheet.getRange(1, 1, parsedData.length, 
parsedData[0].length).setValues(parsedData); 
}
```

The url is an excel sheet with various columns - eg 'Email', 'Name', 'Review Date'.
All this data is now stored in var parsedData. How do I pull out the specific 'Email' column from parsedData?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Read a bit into accessing elements of a JavaScript `Array`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to print a selection from Google App Script (GAS).   There are ways to export to pdf see this link [link](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70)

Comment: Regarding getting the column containing email address, parseData is a 2 dimensional array parseData[i] is each row and parseData[i][j] is the jth column of row i so if you know the column you can loop through the array and extact the email addresses

Comment: Thank you for your help TheWizEd, I worked this out with your help.